# Hibernate option disappeared from power menu in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hibernate

I have Ubuntu 14.04 in my Acer-Aspire-5749 laptop. I have been using it for a few months. The hibernate option was working fine until I rebooted my PC today. Now it has disappeared form the power menu. How to fix this..

`sudo pm-hibernate` is working fine.

Following are the contents of my

`/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` file..

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: Did you try putting the config file into /var/etc as mentioned in http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: Its already there..

Comment: @darwash Ahhhh  The official documentation shows a different file location.  Try placing the file into /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d, as mentioned in https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

Comment: This file is already in that folder..

Comment: All three locations and it still doesn't work?

Comment: yeah :(.. all three..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15510/discussion-between-charles-green-and-darwesh).

Comment: @CharlesGreen its not `var/etc` is simply `etc` that is mentioned in first link you mentioned above.

Comment: I can't login.. :/